# Limit y axis without changing plotted data at all in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I limit the y axis on a ggplot without losing any data? If I limit the y axis with

```
scale_y_continuous()
```

or similar functions, the y axis is limited correctly, but the y values above the limit are not plotted anymore.
Reproducible example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x
df <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5))
```

This returns:
[image]

How do I make the y axis end at 5, but still plot the points above 5?
I ask this because I want to add indicators of significance to a 3-point lineplot comparing two groups without expanding the y axis. What I have right now looks like this:
[image]

I want the y axis to end at 400, but still be able to plot the lines and stars above the ggplot.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "the y axis is limited correctly, but the y values above the limit are not plotted anymore" - what were you expecting? (That's not a rhetorical question!) You can't show data that's outside of your plot!

Comment: @CaptainHat: Thank you for your comment! I was expecting exactly what happened. I posted this example to illustrate what I am looking for: a method to limit the y axis without reducing the space ggplot uses to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you rightly, I think you want to edit the axis **breaks**, rather than the **limits**:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

plot_data <- tibble(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:5,
                     limits = c(1,15))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was going for! Do you know if it is possible to also stop not only the axis ticks and labels, but also the y axis line to be drawn above a specified value?

Comment: You could check out this [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lemon/vignettes/capped-axes.html)